# Does timezone count differ by locale?

Tags: java, timezone, locale

Will `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();` get the same number of timezones regardless of what locale I'm running in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` returns all known time zones and has nothing to do with locale.

I am interested in why you thought it was possible that it could be different based on locale.

As Gunslinger47 points out, time zones do occasionally change and you need to either update to a new JDK/JRE or patch the old one, but again this is independent of locale.

Comment: Not to say that Lance should hardcore the value.  The number of timezones in existence changes all the time, as recently as March 2010.

Comment: But time zone rules are independent of locales, which is why I've edited my answer to ask why he thought it could be different.

Comment: I'm just not very experienced with Java, and I /think/ I've just finished watching Locale.getAvailableLocales() hand back a different number of locales based on the device (I'm writing Android code).  I didn't think TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() would return different timezones based on.. well.. anything... but I just wanted to make sure, and I knew someone more experienced in Java would be able to answer more confidently than I could.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted [Answer by SteveD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2814314/642706) is correct. In addition, you should know you are using an obsolete class.

## `java.time.ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`

The legacy class `TimeZone` has been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html).

To get a list of all time zones, call `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

```
Set< String > zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

As explained above, the JVM’s current default [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) **has *no* effect** on what zones appear in the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) returned by that command.

### Localizing

The [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) *does* have an effect on localizing the name of the zone, when calling [`ZoneId::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) for presentation to the user.

Let's display a list of the ID and the localized name.

```java
Set < String > zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();

TextStyle style = TextStyle.FULL;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;

System.out.println( "zoneId | localized" );
for ( String zoneId : zoneIds )
{
    System.out.println( 
        zoneId + 
        " | " + 
        ZoneId.of( zoneId ).getDisplayName( style , locale ) 
    );
}
```

When run:

```
zoneId | localized
Asia/Aden | heure de l’Arabie
America/Cuiaba | heure de l’Amazonie
Etc/GMT+9 | UTC−9:00
Etc/GMT+8 | UTC−8:00
Africa/Nairobi | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
America/Marigot | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Aqtau | Heure d'Aqtau
Pacific/Kwajalein | Heure des Iles Marshall
America/El_Salvador | heure du Centre
Asia/Pontianak | Heure de l'Indonésie occidentale
Africa/Cairo | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Pacific/Pago_Pago | heure des Samoa
Africa/Mbabane | Afrique du Sud
Asia/Kuching | Heure de Malaisie
Pacific/Honolulu | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Rarotonga | heure des îles Cook
America/Guatemala | heure du Centre
Australia/Hobart | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Europe/London | Heure britannique
America/Belize | heure du Centre
America/Panama | heure de l’Est
Asia/Chungking | heure de Chine
America/Managua | heure du Centre
America/Indiana/Petersburg | heure de l’Est
Asia/Yerevan | heure de l’Arménie
Europe/Brussels | heure d’Europe centrale
GMT | Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Warsaw | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Chicago | heure du Centre
Asia/Kashgar | Chine
Chile/Continental | heure du Chili
Pacific/Yap | Heure de Chuuk
CET | Heure d'Europe centrale
Etc/GMT-1 | UTC+1:00
Etc/GMT-0 | heure moyenne de Greenwich
Europe/Jersey | Heure britannique
America/Tegucigalpa | heure du Centre
Etc/GMT-5 | UTC+5:00
Europe/Istanbul | Heure d'Europe de l'Est
America/Eirunepe | heure de l’Acre
Etc/GMT-4 | UTC+4:00
America/Miquelon | heure de Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon
Etc/GMT-3 | UTC+3:00
Europe/Luxembourg | heure d’Europe centrale
Etc/GMT-2 | UTC+2:00
Etc/GMT-9 | UTC+9:00
America/Argentina/Catamarca | heure de l’Argentine
Etc/GMT-8 | UTC+8:00
Etc/GMT-7 | UTC+7:00
Etc/GMT-6 | UTC+6:00
Europe/Zaporozhye | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Canada/Yukon | heure du Pacifique
Canada/Atlantic | heure de l’Atlantique
Atlantic/St_Helena | Heure de Greenwich
Australia/Tasmania | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Libya | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Europe/Guernsey | Heure britannique
America/Grand_Turk | heure de l’Est
US/Pacific-New | heure du Pacifique
Asia/Samarkand | heure de l’Ouzbékistan
America/Argentina/Cordoba | heure de l’Argentine
Asia/Phnom_Penh | Heure d'Indochine
Africa/Kigali | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Almaty | Heure d'Alma-Ata
US/Alaska | heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Dubai | Golfe
Europe/Isle_of_Man | Heure britannique
America/Araguaina | heure de Brasilia
Cuba | heure de Cuba
Asia/Novosibirsk | heure de Novossibirsk
America/Argentina/Salta | heure de l’Argentine
Etc/GMT+3 | UTC−3:00
Africa/Tunis | heure d’Europe centrale
Etc/GMT+2 | UTC−2:00
Etc/GMT+1 | UTC−1:00
Pacific/Fakaofo | Heure de Tokelau
Africa/Tripoli | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Etc/GMT+0 | heure moyenne de Greenwich
Israel | heure d’Israël
Africa/Banjul | Heure de Greenwich
Etc/GMT+7 | UTC−7:00
Indian/Comoro | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Etc/GMT+6 | UTC−6:00
Etc/GMT+5 | UTC−5:00
Etc/GMT+4 | UTC−4:00
Pacific/Port_Moresby | Heure de Papouasie-Nouvelle-Guinée
US/Arizona | heure des Rocheuses
Antarctica/Syowa | Heure de Syowa
Indian/Reunion | Heure de la Réunion
Pacific/Palau | Heure de Palaos
Europe/Kaliningrad | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Montevideo | heure de l’Uruguay
Africa/Windhoek | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Karachi | heure du Pakistan
Africa/Mogadishu | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Australia/Perth | heure de l’Ouest de l’Australie
Brazil/East | heure de Brasilia
Etc/GMT | heure moyenne de Greenwich
Asia/Chita | heure de Iakoutsk
Pacific/Easter | heure de l’île de Pâques
Antarctica/Davis | Heure de Davis
Antarctica/McMurdo | heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
Asia/Macao | heure de Chine
America/Manaus | heure de l’Amazonie
Africa/Freetown | Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Bucharest | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Tomsk | Tomsk Time
America/Argentina/Mendoza | heure de l’Argentine
Asia/Macau | heure de Chine
Europe/Malta | heure d’Europe centrale
Mexico/BajaSur | heure du Pacifique mexicain
Pacific/Tahiti | Heure de Tahiti
Africa/Asmera | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Europe/Busingen | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos | heure de l’Argentine
Africa/Malabo | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Europe/Skopje | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Catamarca | heure de l’Argentine
America/Godthab | heure de l’Ouest du Groenland
Europe/Sarajevo | heure d’Europe centrale
Australia/ACT | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
GB-Eire | Heure britannique
Africa/Lagos | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Cordoba | heure de l’Argentine
Europe/Rome | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Dacca | heure du Bangladesh
Indian/Mauritius | heure de Maurice
Pacific/Samoa | heure des Samoa
America/Regina | heure du Centre
America/Fort_Wayne | heure de l’Est
America/Dawson_Creek | heure des Rocheuses
Africa/Algiers | heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Mariehamn | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/St_Johns | heure de Terre-Neuve
America/St_Thomas | heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Zurich | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Anguilla | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Dili | Heure de Timor-Leste
America/Denver | heure des Rocheuses
Africa/Bamako | Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Saratov | Saratov Time
GB | Heure britannique
Mexico/General | heure du Centre
Pacific/Wallis | Heure de Wallis-et-Futuna
Europe/Gibraltar | heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Conakry | Heure de Greenwich
Africa/Lubumbashi | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Istanbul | Heure d'Europe de l'Est
America/Havana | heure de Cuba
NZ-CHAT | heure des îles Chatham
Asia/Choibalsan | heure de Choibalsan
America/Porto_Acre | heure de l’Acre
Asia/Omsk | heure d’Omsk
Europe/Vaduz | heure d’Europe centrale
US/Michigan | heure de l’Est
Asia/Dhaka | heure du Bangladesh
America/Barbados | heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Tiraspol | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Atlantic/Cape_Verde | heure du Cap-Vert
Asia/Yekaterinburg | heure d’Ekaterinbourg
America/Louisville | heure de l’Est
Pacific/Johnston | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Chatham | heure des îles Chatham
Europe/Ljubljana | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Sao_Paulo | heure de Brasilia
Asia/Jayapura | Heure d'Indonésie orientale
America/Curacao | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Dushanbe | Heure du Tadjikistan
America/Guyana | Heure de Guyana
America/Guayaquil | Heure de l'Equateur
America/Martinique | heure de l’Atlantique
Portugal | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Europe/Berlin | heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Moscow | heure de Moscou
Europe/Chisinau | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Puerto_Rico | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Rankin_Inlet | heure du Centre
Pacific/Ponape | Ponape
Europe/Stockholm | heure d’Europe centrale
Europe/Budapest | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Argentina/Jujuy | heure de l’Argentine
Australia/Eucla | heure du centre-ouest de l’Australie
Asia/Shanghai | heure de Chine
Universal | Temps universel coordonné
Europe/Zagreb | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Port_of_Spain | heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Helsinki | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Beirut | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Tel_Aviv | heure d’Israël
Pacific/Bougainville | Bougainville Time
US/Central | heure du Centre
Africa/Sao_Tome | Heure de Greenwich
Indian/Chagos | Heure de l'océan Indien
America/Cayenne | Heure de Guyane française
Asia/Yakutsk | heure de Iakoutsk
Pacific/Galapagos | Heure des Galapagos
Australia/North | heure du centre de l’Australie
Europe/Paris | heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Ndjamena | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Pacific/Fiji | heure des îles Fidji
America/Rainy_River | heure du Centre
Indian/Maldives | Heure des Maldives
Australia/Yancowinna | heure du centre de l’Australie
SystemV/AST4 | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Oral | Heure d'Oral
America/Yellowknife | heure des Rocheuses
Pacific/Enderbury | Heure de l'Ile de Phoenix
America/Juneau | heure de l’Alaska
Australia/Victoria | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
America/Indiana/Vevay | heure de l’Est
Asia/Tashkent | heure de l’Ouzbékistan
Asia/Jakarta | Heure de l'Indonésie occidentale
Africa/Ceuta | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Barnaul | Barnaul Time
America/Recife | heure de Brasilia
America/Buenos_Aires | heure de l’Argentine
America/Noronha | heure de Fernando de Noronha
America/Swift_Current | heure du Centre
Australia/Adelaide | heure du centre de l’Australie
America/Metlakatla | heure de l’Alaska
Africa/Djibouti | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
America/Paramaribo | Heure du Surinam
Asia/Qostanay | Kostanay Time
Europe/Simferopol | heure de Moscou
Europe/Sofia | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Africa/Nouakchott | Heure de Greenwich
Europe/Prague | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Vincennes | heure de l’Est
Antarctica/Mawson | Heure de Mawson
America/Kralendijk | heure de l’Atlantique
Antarctica/Troll | Troll Time
Europe/Samara | heure de Samara
Indian/Christmas | Heure de l'Ile Christmas
America/Antigua | heure de l’Atlantique
Pacific/Gambier | Heure de Gambi
America/Indianapolis | heure de l’Est
America/Inuvik | heure des Rocheuses
America/Iqaluit | heure de l’Est
Pacific/Funafuti | Heure de Tuvalu
UTC | Temps universel coordonné
Antarctica/Macquarie | Heure de l'Ile Macquarie
Canada/Pacific | heure du Pacifique
America/Moncton | heure de l’Atlantique
Africa/Gaborone | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Pacific/Chuuk | Heure de Chuuk
Asia/Pyongyang | heure de la Corée
America/St_Vincent | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Gaza | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Etc/Universal | Temps universel coordonné
PST8PDT | heure du Pacifique
Atlantic/Faeroe | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Asia/Qyzylorda | Heure de Kyzylorda
Canada/Newfoundland | heure de Terre-Neuve
America/Kentucky/Louisville | heure de l’Est
America/Yakutat | heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh | Heure d'Indochine
Antarctica/Casey | heure de l’Ouest de l’Australie
Europe/Copenhagen | heure d’Europe centrale
Africa/Asmara | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Atlantic/Azores | heure des Açores
Europe/Vienna | heure d’Europe centrale
ROK | heure de la Corée
Pacific/Pitcairn | Pitcairn
America/Mazatlan | heure du Pacifique mexicain
Australia/Queensland | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Pacific/Nauru | Heure de Nauru
Europe/Tirane | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Kolkata | Inde
SystemV/MST7 | heure des Rocheuses
Australia/Canberra | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
MET | MET
Australia/Broken_Hill | heure du centre de l’Australie
Europe/Riga | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Dominica | heure de l’Atlantique
Africa/Abidjan | Heure de Greenwich
America/Mendoza | heure de l’Argentine
America/Santarem | heure de Brasilia
Kwajalein | Heure des Iles Marshall
America/Asuncion | heure du Paraguay
Asia/Ulan_Bator | heure d’Oulan-Bator
NZ | heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
America/Boise | heure des Rocheuses
Australia/Currie | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
EST5EDT | heure de l’Est
Pacific/Guam | Chamorro
Pacific/Wake | Heure de Wake
Atlantic/Bermuda | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Costa_Rica | heure du Centre
America/Dawson | heure du Pacifique
Asia/Chongqing | heure de Chine
Eire | Heure irlandaise
Europe/Amsterdam | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Knox | heure du Centre
America/North_Dakota/Beulah | heure du Centre
Africa/Accra | Heure du Ghana
Atlantic/Faroe | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Mexico/BajaNorte | heure du Pacifique
America/Maceio | heure de Brasilia
Etc/UCT | Temps universel coordonné
Pacific/Apia | heure d’Apia
GMT0 | heure moyenne de Greenwich
America/Atka | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Niue | Heure de Niue
Australia/Lord_Howe | heure de Lord Howe
Europe/Dublin | Heure irlandaise
Pacific/Truk | Heure de Chuuk
MST7MDT | heure des Rocheuses
America/Monterrey | heure du Centre
America/Nassau | heure de l’Est
America/Jamaica | heure de l’Est
Asia/Bishkek | Heure du Kirghizistan
America/Atikokan | heure de l’Est
Atlantic/Stanley | heure des îles Malouines
Australia/NSW | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
US/Hawaii | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
SystemV/CST6 | heure du Centre
Indian/Mahe | Heure des Seychelles
Asia/Aqtobe | Heure d'Aqtobe
America/Sitka | heure de l’Alaska
Asia/Vladivostok | heure de Vladivostok
Africa/Libreville | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Africa/Maputo | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Zulu | Temps universel coordonné
America/Kentucky/Monticello | heure de l’Est
Africa/El_Aaiun | Heure d'Europe de l'Ouest
Africa/Ouagadougou | Heure de Greenwich
America/Coral_Harbour | heure de l’Est
Pacific/Marquesas | Heure des Marquises
Brazil/West | heure de l’Amazonie
America/Aruba | heure de l’Atlantique
America/North_Dakota/Center | heure du Centre
America/Cayman | heure de l’Est
Asia/Ulaanbaatar | heure d’Oulan-Bator
Asia/Baghdad | heure de l’Arabie
Europe/San_Marino | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Indiana/Tell_City | heure du Centre
America/Tijuana | heure du Pacifique
Pacific/Saipan | Chamorro
SystemV/YST9 | Alaska
Africa/Douala | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Chihuahua | heure du Pacifique mexicain
America/Ojinaga | heure des Rocheuses
Asia/Hovd | heure de Hovd
America/Anchorage | heure de l’Alaska
Chile/EasterIsland | heure de l’île de Pâques
America/Halifax | heure de l’Atlantique
Antarctica/Rothera | Heure de Rothera
America/Indiana/Indianapolis | heure de l’Est
US/Mountain | heure des Rocheuses
Asia/Damascus | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Argentina/San_Luis | heure de l’Ouest argentin
America/Santiago | heure du Chili
Asia/Baku | heure de l’Azerbaïdjan
America/Argentina/Ushuaia | heure de l’Argentine
Atlantic/Reykjavik | Heure de Greenwich
Africa/Brazzaville | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Africa/Porto-Novo | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/La_Paz | Heure de Bolivie
Antarctica/DumontDUrville | Heure de Dumont-d'Urville
Asia/Taipei | heure de Taipei
Antarctica/South_Pole | heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
Asia/Manila | heure des Philippines
Asia/Bangkok | Heure d'Indochine
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Poland | heure d’Europe centrale
Atlantic/Madeira | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Antarctica/Palmer | Heure du Chili
America/Thunder_Bay | heure de l’Est
Africa/Addis_Ababa | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Asia/Yangon | Heure de Myanmar
Europe/Uzhgorod | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Brazil/DeNoronha | heure de Fernando de Noronha
Asia/Ashkhabad | heure du Turkménistan
Etc/Zulu | Temps universel coordonné
America/Indiana/Marengo | heure de l’Est
America/Creston | heure des Rocheuses
America/Punta_Arenas | Punta Arenas Time
America/Mexico_City | heure du Centre
Antarctica/Vostok | Heure de Vostok
Asia/Jerusalem | heure d’Israël
Europe/Andorra | heure d’Europe centrale
US/Samoa | heure des Samoa
PRC | heure de Chine
Asia/Vientiane | Heure d'Indochine
Pacific/Kiritimati | Heure de l'Ile de Line
America/Matamoros | heure du Centre
America/Blanc-Sablon | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Riyadh | heure de l’Arabie
Iceland | Heure de Greenwich
Pacific/Pohnpei | Ponape
Asia/Ujung_Pandang | Heure d'Indonésie centrale
Atlantic/South_Georgia | Géorgie du Sud
Europe/Lisbon | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
Asia/Harbin | heure de Chine
Europe/Oslo | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Novokuznetsk | heure de Krasnoïarsk
CST6CDT | heure du Centre
Atlantic/Canary | heure d’Europe de l’Ouest
America/Knox_IN | heure du Centre
Asia/Kuwait | heure de l’Arabie
SystemV/HST10 | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Efate | heure du Vanuatu
Africa/Lome | Heure de Greenwich
America/Bogota | heure de Colombie
America/Menominee | heure du Centre
America/Adak | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Pacific/Norfolk | Heure de Norfolk
Europe/Kirov | Kirov Time
America/Resolute | heure du Centre
Pacific/Tarawa | Heure de Kiribati
Africa/Kampala | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Asia/Krasnoyarsk | heure de Krasnoïarsk
Greenwich | Heure de Greenwich
SystemV/EST5 | heure de l’Est
America/Edmonton | heure des Rocheuses
Europe/Podgorica | heure d’Europe centrale
Australia/South | heure du centre de l’Australie
Canada/Central | heure du Centre
Africa/Bujumbura | Heure d'Afrique centrale
America/Santo_Domingo | heure de l’Atlantique
US/Eastern | heure de l’Est
Europe/Minsk | heure de Moscou
Pacific/Auckland | heure de la Nouvelle-Zélande
Africa/Casablanca | Heure d'Europe de l'Ouest
America/Glace_Bay | heure de l’Atlantique
Canada/Eastern | heure de l’Est
Asia/Qatar | heure de l’Arabie
Europe/Kiev | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Singapore | Heure de Singapour
Asia/Magadan | heure de Magadan
SystemV/PST8 | Pacifique
America/Port-au-Prince | heure de l’Est
Europe/Belfast | Heure britannique
America/St_Barthelemy | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Ashgabat | heure du Turkménistan
Africa/Luanda | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Nipigon | heure de l’Est
Atlantic/Jan_Mayen | heure d’Europe centrale
Brazil/Acre | heure de l’Acre
Asia/Muscat | Golfe
Asia/Bahrain | heure de l’Arabie
Europe/Vilnius | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Fortaleza | heure de Brasilia
Etc/GMT0 | heure moyenne de Greenwich
US/East-Indiana | heure de l’Est
America/Hermosillo | heure du Pacifique mexicain
America/Cancun | heure de l’Est
Africa/Maseru | Afrique du Sud
Pacific/Kosrae | Heure de Kusaie
Africa/Kinshasa | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Asia/Kathmandu | Heure du Népal
Asia/Seoul | heure de la Corée
Australia/Sydney | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
America/Lima | heure du Pérou
Australia/LHI | heure de Lord Howe
America/St_Lucia | heure de l’Atlantique
Europe/Madrid | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Bahia_Banderas | heure du Centre
America/Montserrat | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Brunei | Heure du Brunei
America/Santa_Isabel | heure du Nord-Ouest du Mexique
Canada/Mountain | heure des Rocheuses
America/Cambridge_Bay | heure des Rocheuses
Asia/Colombo | Inde
Australia/West | heure de l’Ouest de l’Australie
Indian/Antananarivo | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
Australia/Brisbane | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Indian/Mayotte | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
US/Indiana-Starke | heure du Centre
Asia/Urumqi | Chine
US/Aleutian | heure d’Hawaï-Aléoutiennes
Europe/Volgograd | heure de Volgograd
America/Lower_Princes | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Vancouver | heure du Pacifique
Africa/Blantyre | Heure d'Afrique centrale
America/Rio_Branco | heure de l’Acre
America/Danmarkshavn | Heure de Greenwich
America/Detroit | heure de l’Est
America/Thule | heure de l’Atlantique
Africa/Lusaka | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Asia/Hong_Kong | heure de Hong Kong
Iran | heure de l’Iran
America/Argentina/La_Rioja | heure de l’Argentine
Africa/Dakar | Heure de Greenwich
SystemV/CST6CDT | heure du Centre
America/Tortola | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Porto_Velho | heure de l’Amazonie
Asia/Sakhalin | heure de Sakhaline
Etc/GMT+10 | UTC−10:00
America/Scoresbysund | heure de l’Est du Groenland
Asia/Kamchatka | heure de Petropavlovsk-Kamchatski
Asia/Thimbu | Heure du Bhoutan
Africa/Harare | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Etc/GMT+12 | UTC−12:00
Etc/GMT+11 | UTC−11:00
Navajo | heure des Rocheuses
America/Nome | heure de l’Alaska
Europe/Tallinn | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Turkey | Heure d'Europe de l'Est
Africa/Khartoum | Heure d'Afrique centrale
Africa/Johannesburg | Afrique du Sud
Africa/Bangui | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
Europe/Belgrade | heure d’Europe centrale
Jamaica | heure de l’Est
Africa/Bissau | Heure de Greenwich
Asia/Tehran | heure de l’Iran
WET | Heure d'Europe de l'Ouest
Europe/Astrakhan | Astrakhan Time
Africa/Juba | Heure d'Afrique de l'Est
America/Campo_Grande | heure de l’Amazonie
America/Belem | heure de Brasilia
Etc/Greenwich | Heure de Greenwich
Asia/Saigon | Heure d'Indochine
America/Ensenada | heure du Pacifique
Pacific/Midway | heure des Samoa
America/Jujuy | heure de l’Argentine
Africa/Timbuktu | Heure de Greenwich
America/Bahia | heure de Brasilia
America/Goose_Bay | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Virgin | heure de l’Atlantique
America/Pangnirtung | heure de l’Est
Asia/Katmandu | Heure du Népal
America/Phoenix | heure des Rocheuses
Africa/Niamey | heure d’Afrique de l’Ouest
America/Whitehorse | heure du Pacifique
Pacific/Noumea | heure de la Nouvelle-Calédonie
Asia/Tbilisi | heure de la Géorgie
America/Montreal | heure de l’Est
Asia/Makassar | Heure d'Indonésie centrale
America/Argentina/San_Juan | heure de l’Argentine
Hongkong | heure de Hong Kong
UCT | Temps universel coordonné
Asia/Nicosia | heure d’Europe de l’Est
America/Indiana/Winamac | heure de l’Est
SystemV/MST7MDT | heure des Rocheuses
America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia | heure de l’Argentine
America/Boa_Vista | heure de l’Amazonie
America/Grenada | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Atyrau | heure : Atyraou
Australia/Darwin | heure du centre de l’Australie
Asia/Khandyga | heure de Iakoutsk
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur | Heure de Malaisie
Asia/Famagusta | Eastern European Time
Asia/Thimphu | Heure du Bhoutan
Asia/Rangoon | Heure de Myanmar
Europe/Bratislava | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Calcutta | Inde
America/Argentina/Tucuman | heure de l’Argentine
Asia/Kabul | Heure d'Afghanistan
Indian/Cocos | Heure des Iles Cocos
Japan | heure du Japon
Pacific/Tongatapu | heure des Tonga
America/New_York | heure de l’Est
Etc/GMT-12 | UTC+12:00
Etc/GMT-11 | UTC+11:00
Etc/GMT-10 | UTC+10:00
SystemV/YST9YDT | heure de l’Alaska
Europe/Ulyanovsk | Ulyanovsk Time
Etc/GMT-14 | UTC+14:00
Etc/GMT-13 | UTC+13:00
W-SU | heure de Moscou
America/Merida | heure du Centre
EET | Heure d'Europe de l'Est
America/Rosario | heure de l’Argentine
Canada/Saskatchewan | heure du Centre
America/St_Kitts | heure de l’Atlantique
Arctic/Longyearbyen | heure d’Europe centrale
America/Fort_Nelson | heure des Rocheuses
America/Caracas | Heure du Venezuela
America/Guadeloupe | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Hebron | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Indian/Kerguelen | Heure des Terres australes antarctiques françaises
SystemV/PST8PDT | heure du Pacifique
Africa/Monrovia | Heure de Greenwich
Asia/Ust-Nera | heure de Vladivostok
Egypt | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Asia/Srednekolymsk | Srednekolymsk Time
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem | heure du Centre
Asia/Anadyr | heure d’Anadyr
Australia/Melbourne | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
Asia/Irkutsk | heure d’Irkoutsk
America/Shiprock | heure des Rocheuses
America/Winnipeg | heure du Centre
Europe/Vatican | heure d’Europe centrale
Asia/Amman | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Etc/UTC | Temps universel coordonné
SystemV/AST4ADT | heure de l’Atlantique
Asia/Tokyo | heure du Japon
America/Toronto | heure de l’Est
Asia/Singapore | Heure de Singapour
Australia/Lindeman | heure de l’Est de l’Australie
America/Los_Angeles | heure du Pacifique
SystemV/EST5EDT | heure de l’Est
Pacific/Majuro | Heure des Iles Marshall
America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires | heure de l’Argentine
Europe/Nicosia | heure d’Europe de l’Est
Pacific/Guadalcanal | Heure des Iles Salomon
Europe/Athens | heure d’Europe de l’Est
US/Pacific | heure du Pacifique
Europe/Monaco | heure d’Europe centrale
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

If you have computers running in different timezones that are running the exact same Java version, then `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();` will return the same result on those computers.

However, the list can (and does) change between different Java versions (even between different update versions).

Why are you asking this question; what's the underlying problem you're trying to solve with the answer to your question? I think it's not a good idea to write a program that has expectations about what the result of `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();` looks like, since the Java API does not make any promises with regard to this.

Comment: I was up against a need to map Java's timezones to a list of a subset supported by a third-party system.  I'm no longer up against that problem, but this question came to mind in the meantime.